# Undetected Chrome Drive Randomly Stopping (Idle Problem)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

My code opens n number of websites one by one using the "undetected Chrome driver" but somehow the driver will stop opening the website randomly(idle). it is completely random when it stops websites it will stop without giving any errors (just being idle)
it does not throw any errors it just freezes so if anyone knows why please suggest a solution thank you in advance.

```
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    
    
    # Initialize webdriver and open website
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions') # Disable browser extensions
    options.add_argument('----disable-javascript')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows')
    
    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True,options=options,service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    
    
    
    with open('PlayerLinks.txt', 'r') as file:
        url = [line.strip() for line in file]
    
    url_=0
    for i in range(166):
        try:
            driver.get(url[url_])
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Time out!!")
        url_+=1
        print(url_)
```